# I have thought/thought of some ideas for the matter

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

Here is a situation. There was something bad you need to tell your parents. But, your parents get upset very easily. So, you and your brother decided to take several days to come up with some ideas to tell your parents without causing trouble. So several days have passed, and you ask your brother whether he has some ideas. Even though **he had thought of some good ideas**, **he forgot them totally** because he was too busy with another matter. In this case, can he say both the answers below?

> **A:** I **thought** of some good ideas but I don't remember. I am sorry.
>
> **B:** I **have thought** of some good ideas but I don't remember. I am sorry.

Comment: Either is fine. A uses *simple past* tense, B uses *past perfect*.

Comment: I think B is **present** perfect, it uses have  not had. Implies more immediacy, and therefore I think less appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I would add **them**, to emphasise what it is that is not remembered; we forgot the specific thoughts, not the fact that we had some thoughts.

Although in isolation both

> I thought of some good ideas but I don't remember them.

and

> I have thought of some good ideas but I don't remember them.

seem grammatically correct, the second does not work for me, a native English speaker. When we say

> I have thought of some good ideas

we are using present perfect tense, which implies a sense of completion or continuation to the present. It therefore clashes with forgetting the ideas.

> I had thought of some good ideas, but I don't remember them

uses past perfect and suggests completion some time ago, before something else happened, in this case before forgetting happened.

See [this reference](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/past_perfect.htm#perfect).

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind, neat answer. Your answer really sorts out my problem and is very helpful. Also appreciate the link.

Answer (score 1):

Given your scenario, here are answers a native speaker might give to the question:

> I **did think** of some things to say but **forget** what they were.
>
> I **did think** of some things to say but **have forgotten** them.
>
> I **had thought** of some things to say but **forgot** what they were.

As djna remarks, the present perfect is incompatible here because it implies the ideas are still fresh in the mind:

> I **have thought** of some things to say but have forgotten them. <sup>NO</sup>

However, there are contexts where the present perfect would be fine, if its meaning is "experienced in my lifetime":

> I **have been** to that theater, but it was so long ago that I've
>   forgotten what movie I saw there.

The incompatibility or compatibility is semantic.

Comment: As always, thank you for the brilliant answer very much. You explained things in a way I couldn't imagine, so your answer has broaden my sight and understanding to this matter. But, in the first sentence you took as an example, doesn't ***forget*** have to be ***forgot*** or either is okay?